# fingerprintjs2 how to obtain get function results?

Tags: javascript, fingerprintjs2

```javascript

```
    'use strict';
    import FingerPrint from 'fingerprintjs2';

    var fingerprint = new FingerPrint();
    var dfp = fingerprint.get(function(dfp, components){
        console.log(dfp);
        return dfp;
    })

    console.log('dfp' + dfp);
```

```

here, result is :
`js
dfpundefined
67bf907b9447de2c085b9fdf3dd1ad23`

the second console.log return first with undefined and first console comes second.

I want to return correct result instead of underfind? how can I ?

thx!